# How can I run multiple Consumers in my java application using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer

[image]

I want to run multiple consumers to test rebalancing in kafka but I am getting above error

Comment: A wild suggestion. Try initiating them with tests. Give easy names to your tests and trigger them ( without recompile ) from a command line. ( Instead of main call it functionA. Initialize the class in each test and call functionA )

Comment: are you trying to run multiple consumer threads, by launching the program multiple times?

Comment: yes I am trying to run more than one consumer with same groupId

Comment: you should create the threads inside your program, not launching multiple ones.

Comment: In the Run Configuration, did you check "single instance"?

Answer (score 1):

[intellij run config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBlRZ.png)

In run configurations select Allow parallel run with this enabled you can run multiple consumers in intellij